# Regular expression to find lines not containing a certain word

Tags: regex

I would like to find all occurrences of the below pattern.

```
import com.pack1.pack2.blah1.className1 ;
import com.pack1.pack2.blah2.className2 ;
import com.pack1.DifferentPackage.blah3.className3 ;
```

I want to find all import statements which will match the third line.

Something like below

```
import com.pack1.!(pack2).*
```

I tried a few examples from tutorials - but couldn't achieve the objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) here.

```
import com\.pack1\.(?!pack2\b).*
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wU1zX9/4)

The word boundary `\b` asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not. Also since you state you are looking for lines, you may want to add beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors.

```
^import com\.pack1\.(?!pack2\b).*$
```

Comment: +1, It cleared My doubts about Negative - lookarounds

Comment: how about `import com.pack1.pack20.blah1.className3 ;`

Comment: Thanks . I will try this - That would really save a lot of time for me.

Comment: I tried this using the regex search in TextPad editor - it did not work . I will check what version of regex is being used . I searched for the string "import com\.pack1\.(?!pack2\b).*" - Should I do something else ?